# Circular dependency between tasks in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

I'm having trouble with circular dependency when trying to build a flutter app that uses a sdk we import inside the android Gradle. If we try to build the Android native app we are able to build the app, otherwise it gives us this output:
I'm putting the build.gradle(App) and build.gradle(Android), the project we are trying to build is the Flutter Demo, with just the build.gradle modifications.
Anyone already saw this kind of problem in Flutter? I'm starting to think there is some kind of conflict between the Flutter builder and the sdk we want to use.

```
    * What went wrong:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
\--- :app:processDebugResources
     \--- :app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug
          \--- :app:mergeDebugAssets
               \--- :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (*)
```

build.gradle(:app)

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'tymodule-config'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.teste2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // required tuya home sdk
    implementation 'com.tuya.smart:tuyasmart:3.17.6'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

build.gradle(:android)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven-other.tuya.com/repository/maven-releases/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven-other.tuya.com/repository/maven-snapshots/'
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.tuya.android.module:tymodule-config:0.4.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven-other.tuya.com/repository/maven-releases/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven-other.tuya.com/repository/maven-snapshots/'
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Well after a lot of struggling, with the flutter update to version 1.2.0 and adding the line closeJDM= true inside gradle.properties and enabling multidex finally I could run the app, we already had tried the closeJDM, but with the flutter update everything worked just fine, I think this issue is closed already, thank you.